# Inconsistencies in looping through the private properties of a subclass

Tags: php, reflection

I was trying to loop through the private properties of a class. The method which would perform this loop is contained in a parent class. Consider the following code:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    private $childProp = "childPropValue";
}

class ParentClass {
    private $parentProp = "parentPropValue";

    public function PrintProperties()
    {
        echo "--- print_r(\$this) ---\n";
        print_r($this);

        echo "\n\n--- foreach(\$this) ---\n";
        foreach($this as $propKey => $propValue) {
            print_r($propKey . ":");
            print_r($propValue . "\n");
        }

        echo "\n\n--- reflection->getProperties ---\n";
        $refl = new \ReflectionClass($this);
        print_r($refl->getProperties());
    }
}

$child = new ChildClass();
$child->PrintProperties();
```

This outputs:

```
--- print_r($this) ---
ChildClass Object
(
    [childProp:ChildClass:private] => childPropValue
    [parentProp:ParentClass:private] => parentPropValue
)


--- foreach($this) ---
parentProp:parentPropValue


--- reflection->getProperties ---
Array
(
    [0] => ReflectionProperty Object
        (
            [name] => childProp
            [class] => ChildClass
        )

)
```

The print_r($this) correctly identifies $this as a ChildClass object and it then lists 2 private properties for this object and lists 2 corresponding class for the property.It could be argued that print_r is only for debugging purposes, so printing both properties is useful in that regard.

Now, the foreach($this) loop uses the same variable as the print_r, but here only the parentProp is listed. This behaviour is probably intuitive since this construct is used to loop through accessible properties.

The reflection method, however, prints exactly the opposite and only lists the 'childProp', which in inaccessible in this scope. Is the fact that this produces  different results because the class name is ChildClass and reflection uses that name to determine the properties?

I think I answered my own question here, but would still like to know other people's opinion on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

The second option, foreach, only can see public and protected values, like you say, but i think \ReflectionClass use filter by default ALL.

You can't see the parent private properties in the ChildClass i think, you need create a construct/gettter for access or change $parentProp to protected.

**print_r($this) ->** I think obvious any privacy limitation, so see all

**foreach($this) ->** I think take in $this the parentClass accesible key values only, which is where it is created, and can only access variables of parentClass

**ReflectionProperty ->** I think create a Children class and cant access to private properties of parentClass

Sorry for my bad english ^^U